# What version of Expo should I use to integrate react-native-google-mobile-ads?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-google-mobile-ads

What is the recommended version of the expo to integrate `react-native-google-mobile-ads`?

I have tried integrating the `react-native-google-mobile-ads` with Expo v48. But unfortunately, I got an error.

```
**Error:** "Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: 'RNGoogleMobileAdsBannerView' was not found in the UIManager".
```

```
# app.json

{
    "expo": {
    ...
    },
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
      "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
```

Comment: any version is fine, AFAIK it needs expo-dev-client

Answer (score 0):

make sure you follow the setup properly, add admob id on app.json config

```
// <project-root>/app.json
{
  "expo": {
    // ...
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Source: https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads

Comment: Yes, I follow the setup as they have mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: did you recreate build development apk and include the library? this error is show that it can't find the library because using old apk without the library. On Dev client, the troublesome part is that you need to recreate the apk after adding new library that require dev-client, but no need if library supported directly from expo

Comment: Yes, I recreate the build development APK. When I install the APK and try to open it on Expo Go. The app is not getting open don't know what the issue is.

Comment: no, don't use expo go, use the app installed, for the command use expo start --dev-client

Comment: I download the app, and for the command I use `expo start --dev-client`. When I open the app I got this message `App keeps stopping`.

Comment: please share your app.json and your code for the ads

Comment: I'm using this library on all my apps, no issue at all

Comment: Is it necessary to use a real App ID from AdMob? Currently, I'm using a dummy ID the same as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: For config on app.json, yes, real app id, for testing use testing unit id like banner interstitial, change it if prod env to real